# PHP MySQL Jquery - Duplicate rows on a filter list

Tags: php, jquery

I'm getting duplicate rows when I filter a list. Before I filter the list, there are no duplicate values, only when I filter it.

Any ideas?

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Filter models" title="Type in a name">


<ul id="myUL">

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","un","pw","db");
    $listdbtables = array_column(mysqli_fetch_all($con->query('SHOW TABLES FROM searcher_toshiba')),0);
    foreach ($listdbtables as $key => $value) {
        $sqlqry = "select model, realmodelname from ".$value." GROUP BY model";
        $nameResult = mysqli_query($con,$sqlqry);
        while($nam = $nameResult->fetch_array()) {

          echo'<li><a href="toshiba/codes.php?model=' . $nam['model'] . '">' . $nam['realmodelname'] . '</a></li>';
        }
    }

</ul>
```

The script:

```
  function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
          a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
          txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              li[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
              li[i].style.display = "none";
          }
      }
  }
```

I tried the fetch_assoc but that didn't work.

```
        while($nam = $nameResult->fetch_assoc()) {
```

I also tried array unique, that didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I was wrong, the query is producting duplicates before the filter.

I tried:

```
        $sqlqry = "select (DISTINCT)model, realmodelname from ".$value." GROUP BY model";
```

but got the same duplicate results.

Thanks,

Comment: i think your problem will be here `li[i].style.display = "";` the display should be block or something like that and can not be empty string without value

Comment: Is it because the list is dynamic?

Comment: no empty value is not allowed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: dump `$listdbtables` it may contains multiple records for search and can make duplicates because you run it in foreach

Comment: what do you mean dumb?

Comment: what? no dumb but dump .. use var_dump and check result of show tables

Answer (score 0):

My solution ended up being:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM mydb LIKE "e%"
```